# Only executing if a matrix checkbox has a specific value

Tags: matrix, checkboxes

I currently have checkboxes in a matrix block that allow a user to select where an image will be placed in the layout (as a featured slider image and/or in an image gallery). I've gotten the slider image to function but if, for some reason, there are no featured images I have a couple of unnecessary `<div>` tags. Because I am selecting only featured images from the matrix block I can not use `loop.first` and `loop.last` to move those divs in my for loop.

I had seen an article that seems close to finding the answer to my problem here : [Only execute twig block if a Matrix radio has a certain value](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8915/only-execute-twig-block-if-a-matrix-radio-has-a-certain-value) but I haven't been able to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{# Add Feature Images - Slideshow #}
    {% set photos = entry.photoGallery.type( 'photos' ) %}
    {% if photos|length %}
    <div class="row" >
            <div class="slidr">
                {% for block in photos if block.imageLocation.contains('featured')%}
                    {# Get the photo #}
                    {% for photo in block.photo %}
                      <div class="figure">
                        <a href="{{ photo.getUrl }}">
                          <img src="{{ photo.getUrl('projectHero') }}" alt="">
                        </a>
                        {# Get the caption #}
                        {% if block.caption|length %}
                          <div class="caption">{{ block.caption }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

I've attached a screen snapshot of my field setup.
[image: screen snapshot of matrix field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get things working but I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this. Any feedback is welcome.

Here's the new code.

```
    {# Grab all the photo entries #}
    {% set photos = entry.photoGallery.type( 'photos' ) %}

    {# create a blank array to merge content #}
    {% set selectedFeaturedImages = [] %}

    {% for block in photos %}
        {# Add Featured Images to an array #}
        {% if block.imageLocation.contains('featured') %}
            {% set selectedFeaturedImages = selectedFeaturedImages|merge([block]) %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for block in selectedFeaturedImages %}
        {% if loop.first %}
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="slidr">
        {% endif %}

            {% for photo in block.photo %}
        <div class="figure"><a href="{{ photo.getUrl }}"><img src="{{ photo.getUrl('projectHero') }}" alt=""></a>
            {# Get the caption #}
            {% if block.caption|length %}
            <div class="caption">{{ block.caption }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
            {% endfor %}

        {% if loop.last %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer as I haven't had any feedback from anyone else and it is functioning properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
{% if block.checkboxFieldHandle.contains('someChkbxValue') %}
<p>Executed!</p>
{% endif %}
```

actual for Craft v2.x and v3.x

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you have the following line wrong:

`{% for block in photos if block.imageLocation.contains('featured') %}`

You will need to use the field name you're using to filter the Matrix block in place of `contains`. The following line will only loop through block with the `imageLocation` field set to "featured".

`{% for block in photos.imageLocation('featured') %}`

Comment: I had tried tried what you suggested but that gives all of the entries regardless if 'featured' is checked.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I see in the craft docs that "you can tell if the option is selected or not via `option.selected`." but I'm unsure how to make that work in the if statement.

Like I mentioned in the original post. The above code works but I want to be able to hide the divs if there are no featured images.